# jQuery: create regex pattern from variable

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I'm trying to create a regex pattern out of a variable like:

```
var tag = "style";
var pattern = "/<"+tag+"[^>]*>((\\n|.)*)<\\/"+tag+">/gi";
```

but it won't work - anyone can tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There's probably a better way to find the html tag that you're looking for using jquery selectors.

Answer (score 5):

Use the RegExp object

```
var tag = "style";
var pattern = new RegExp("<"+tag+"[^>]*>((\\n|.)*)<\\/"+tag+">","gi");
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, matching html tags with regex isn't a good idea.  See [explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-rege).

Answer (score 0):

var re = new RegExp(string) ..

see [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml)